# how to increase kube-prometheus-stack startupProbe?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-prometheus-stack

Hi I am looking in the values.yaml file of the helm chart `kube-prometheus-stack` and I am not able to find the key/value for the `startupProbe`. I've got an issue where loading of the prometheus pod takes more time than the default which is 15 min and I am trying to increase it, also trying to editing the `statefulset` would not work as they would be get overwritten by the prometheus itself. could anyone help me with this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can just override default `startupProbe` settings in `Prometheuses` custom resource as follows:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: prometheus
      startupProbe:
        failureThreshold: 120
```

Comment: Maybe it is worth adding the source (https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/user-guides/strategic-merge-patch.md) and specifying that is not enough to edit the resource but to patch it with merge strategy

Answer (score 0):

seems like here is what you need

edit `Prometheus` resource, e.g

```
$ k -n <ns> get prometheus <name> -o yaml

apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
...
spec:
...
  containers:
  - name: prometheus
    startupProbe:
      failureThreshold: 300
```

and if need to change it in Helm values file

```
prometheus:
...
  prometheusSpec:
    containers: 
    - name: prometheus
      startupProbe:
        failureThreshold: 300
```